# How to pass char buffer to Poco Context class constructor?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, poco-libraries

Right now I am passing private key file path to Context Class mentioned below. Due to security reasons I will not get file path for private key.
I am using this for SSL Connection with server.

Problem:
Now I will get char buffer instead of private key file path. how can i pass char buffer to Context class constructor ?

Please help  me on this ..

I am talking about **Poco/Net/Context.h** this class.

Ref:

```
             Context(
                Usage usage,
                const std::string & privateKeyFile,
                const std::string & certificateFile,
                const std::string & caLocation,
                VerificationMode verificationMode = VERIFY_RELAXED,
                int verificationDepth = 9,
                bool loadDefaultCAs = false,
                const std::string & cipherList = "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH"
            );
```

if we use usePrivateKey and useCertificate
then how the Context can be defined ?

```
  Context::Ptr ptrContext = new Context(Context::TLSV1_2_CLIENT_USE, "", "", 
  "ca.crt", Context::VERIFY_STRICT, 9, true, 
  "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
```

is the above ok?
if i use **usePrivateKey** and **useCertificate** and then in Context if i give the filpath of private key and certificate as empty will the ssl context still use the private key and certificate

Comment: Can you use void useCertificate(
    const Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate & certificate
); and void usePrivateKey(
    const Poco::Crypto::RSAKey & key
); instead ?

Comment: Not knowing Poco, so cannot hint to alternative approaches - but if all other alternatives fail for whichever reason, as *last ressort* you might *try* named pipes.